# Rubix vs Blockapps vs others, what are the differences in private Ethereum platforms?

Tags: private-blockchain, blockapps

What are the major differences between the different private Ethereum platforms? The main two that I am aware of are Rubix and Blockapps, what are the primary differences?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge Rubix is more consulting around blockchain than an actual platform. BlockApps built the Haskell implementation of ethereum and a REST api to interact with your node or network, http://blockapps.net/documentation.

Comment: No, Rubix is a platform, check their site